# Parsing error with field calculator

Tags: python

I am trying to do a simple calculation that populates a field based on a set of acreage figures.  I am using if/else if statements with acreage ranges.  Here is the python script I came up with.

```
def reLabel(acres):
  if acres > 0 and acres <= 10:
    return "1"
  elif acres > 0 and acres < 20:
    return "2"
  elif acres> 0 and acres < 30:
    return "3"
  elif acres > 0 and acres < 40:
    return "4"
  elif acres > 0 and acres < 50:
    return "5"
  elif acres > 0 and acres > 50:
    return "6"
  else:
    return "0"

relabel (GIS_acre)
```

I hope that shows up correctly...

I keep getting an error that says `syntax error unexpected EOF while parsing (<expresion>, line 1)`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Just curious, why do your rankings overlap? eg. case 1 acres >0 and <20 returns 2   and case 2 acres > 0 and <30 (overlaps case 1) returns 3. Should case 1 be  >0 and <= 20 and case 2 be acres >20 and <30?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a typo. Python is case sensitive, also space between brackets and function not allowed. Change 
relabel (GIS_acre)
to
reLabel(GIS_acre)
and try again.